# polymer 3.x fullcalendar import error on the component

Tags: fullcalendar, polymer-3.x

I have a problem with importing the Fullcalendar JS library. I installed it with NPM together with momentjs and jquery.

However, I encounter this error in my browser.

```
fullcalendar.js:211 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:211)
at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:743)
at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:347)
at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:1944)
at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:11)
at fullcalendar.js:20
at fullcalendar.js:20
```

Here are the imports for the component.

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '@polymer/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.js';
import './shared-styles.js';
import 'jquery';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'fullcalendar';
```

How do I solve this issue?

PS: most fullcalendar wrappers or components are not migrated into polymer 3.x

Comment: Try the instructions here how to import: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/installation

Comment: Hello @HakanC, the import is already there in the code but the error shown above is causing my element to not work.

Comment: I don't know how to fix but says: `Then, you must install a build system like Webpack or Browserify that will automatically bundle all of your code. See an example repo that uses Webpack »`

Comment: I’m not sure if polymer requires that but I’ll take a look into it.

Comment: If you need calendar element, I think you can find Polymer's native calendar or date picker elements. Something like I used before mp-calendar (at webcomponents.org)

Comment: I’m actually looking for a calendar that can keep track of the events. The elements in offered are usually just selecting the date and it’s missing the event tracker. Do you have any alternatives?

Comment: You can use for events also. See my app visitsapp.com (you can add meeting etc, ) Not only date picker.

Comment: Oh that’s very nice! I’ll still leave this problem open until a proper solution is posted. I’ll check into your element when I come back from the holidays.